# Do GetManifestResourceStream() items have to be in Resources?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I copied a file, `vbaProject.bin` into the root of my VS.net project (I want it to be highly visible, not in a subfolder). I selected it and set the Build Action to Embedded Resource. Then I did this in my code...

```
App = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Ans = App.GetManifestResourceStream("vbaProject.bin")
```

Ans is always Nothing. `GetManifestResourceStream` is a bit of a black box to me, can if find this resource in the "root"? If so, do I have the name correct, or do I need some sort of path here?

**UPDATE:** Following Michael's suggestion, I did this:

```
App = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Ans = App.GetManifestResourceStream(App.GetName().ToString().Split(","c)(0) & ".vbaProject.bin")
```

Is that a safe solution?

Comment: As a debugging aid, call GetManifestResourceNames() and inspect the result to make sure the resource was correctly embedded with the name you're expecting.

Comment: @MichaelLiu - extremely useful! I found it, "CBLDynaTools.vbaProject.bin" So how do I get the "CBLDynaTools" part so I can build the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to rely on the behavior of Visual Studio, then you could do something like this:

```
Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
Dim firstType As Type = asm.GetTypes(0)
Dim rootNamespace As String = firstType.Namespace
Dim myFileName As String = "something.bin"
Dim strm As IO.Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(rootNamespace & "." & myFileName)
```

This relies on the behavior of Visual Studio to pre-pend the root namespace to the embedded file's name.

A better solution is to modify the `ProjectName.vbproj` file (MS Build file) to specify the exact name you want to use.  You should find an `<ItemGroup>` that contains the directive to embed the file.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="DirectoryPath\something.bin" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

change the above to specify the [LogicalName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx) tag that will provide the name to use.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="DirectoryPath\something.bin">
      <LogicalName>something.bin</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Close Visual Studio and edit the `ProjectName.vbproj` in a text editor.  This change will be preserved when you load the project in Visual Studio.

With this change, now you can obtain the stream like this:

```
Dim myFileName As String = "something.bin"
Dim strm As IO.Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(myFileName)
```